# Relationship of significance level and p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

In a hypothesis test, the null hypothesis $H_0$ is rejected in favor of $H_1$ if $|\bar X|>\mu$.

When tests found that $\bar x$ is the mean of the samples, a p-value is computed using

$$
p=\Pr(|\bar X|>\bar x)
$$
Using (e.g $\bar X\sim t(n-1) $ the p-value is obtained and the conclusion is:

> Tests with significance level $\alpha≥p$ rejects the null hypothesis

---

This does not make sense to me. What does the p-value have to do with the significance level?

$p$ only tells the probability of obtaining $\bar X ≥\bar x$ or values as extreme as $\bar x$

On the other hand, $\alpha=\Pr(\bar X\in C)$ where $C$ is the critical region (i.e. $\Pr(|\bar X|>\mu)$) or the probability of exceeding the value $\mu$ as set by the practicioner.

I am struggling to see any formal connection between the two. Please help me connect their concepts. Thank you

Comment: you may use the pvalue without any reference to alpha if you wish.

Comment: @utobi can you please elaborate or provide reference sources? My textbook only discuss p-values with the context of significance levels. Thank you

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595373/56940 and other similar threads in this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more of a commentary in a broader sense but worth mentioning.

As framed in $\mathrm{ [I]}$ (sec. $14.2.4,$ p. $688$), $p$-value was developed by Fisher to (emphasis mine)

> [...] evaluate the  worst-case scenario for the null hypothesis in the
> sense that it involves the observed value of the statistic and realizations more damning
> for the null. It measures the probability of observing a sample realization that would
> produce a statistic value equal to or worse than the one already observed.
> [I]f the p-value is small this implies that either the observed realization of the test statistic
> constitutes a very rare event or the postulated null hypothesis is invalid.
> In cases where the p-value is small the first choice is considered practically impossible and
> the modeler adopts the view that the postulated hypothesis is invalid. ... In the early stages of his work
> **Fisher suggested $p$-values of $0.05$ and $0.01$ to be used as intuitive thresholds. Later on,
> however, he insisted that one should separate the $p$-value from the decision to accept or
> reject $H_0.$**

The author conspicuously reminds (sec. $14.2.5,$ p. $692$) the readers:

> In a certain sense the $p$-value represents the worst-case
> scenario for the null hypothesis, taking into account not just the observed
> sample realization but also more unfavorable realizations. **The question of
> accepting or rejecting $H_0$ is a separate issue and the $p$-value should not be confused with the significance level of the Neyman–Pearson testing framework** [...]

and again in the same vein (sec. $14.3.5,$ p. $703$):

> Even though the two can be related
> mathematically, they constitute very different notions in different contexts. **The
> role of the $p$-value is *inferential* and that of the significance level is *decision
> making*. This is why the use of $p$-values in the context of the Neyman–Pearson
> approach was considered to be a sacrilege by Fisher ($1956$).**

Please check [$p$-value: Fisherian vs. contemporary frequentist definitions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386369/p-value-fisherian-vs-contemporary-frequentist-definitions) and other links therein.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Probability Theory
and Statistical Inference:
Econometric Modeling
with Observational Data, *Aris Spanos,* Cambridge University Press, $1999.$

Comment: >"The role of the p-value is inferential and that of the significance level is decision making". With this statement and other answers, does it conclude that p-values are the **guidelines** to determine at which significant level the null hypothesis would be rejected? P-values are used to infer what significance levels the test would fail and the final decision making does not take p-values to consideration but only the significance level?

Comment: You can take $p$-value as the smallest level of significance at which you can reject the null hypothesis based on the observation.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that $\mu$ is the critical value at test level $\alpha$. Then the test rejects the $H_0$ if observed $|\bar x|\ge \mu$ (the case of equality is irrelevant if the distribution of $\bar X$ is continuous, but "$\ge$" here will correspond to "$\ge$" in "$\alpha\ge p$"). Also, ${\rm Pr}\{|\bar X|\ge\mu\}={\rm Pr}(\bar X\in C)=\alpha$ (assuming that the test is exact).

Note that the t-test relies on a test statistic that has $\bar X$ linearly transformed and involves the standard error; the argument there is the same (using the statistic $T$ instead of $\bar X$) but I will here focus on just $\bar X$ as test statistic as in the question, which is the case in a Gauss-test with known variance and the null hypothesis that the underlying mean is zero. Note also that $\mu$ is more often used to denote the hypothesised mean rather than the critical value, but I'll stick to the notation in the question.

Now $p={\rm Pr}\{|\bar X|\ge |\bar x|\}$ (note that the absolute value should here also be taken of the $\bar x$). If $\alpha\ge p$, this means that $|\bar x|\ge \mu$, and therefore the test rejects, because it means that the set
$\{|\bar X|\ge |\bar x|\}$ must be a subset of or equal to the set $\{|\bar X|\ge \mu\}$. Note that it can only be a subset, equal, or a superset, and it can't be a superset, because then $\alpha<p$ (assuming $\mu$ to be chosen as the smallest possible value that makes ${\rm Pr}\{|\bar X|\ge\mu\}=\alpha$, which as appropriately defined critical value it should be - if the density of $\bar X$ is larger than zero around $\mu$ as in the Gauss-test, this is automatically the case).

In many tests including the Gauss-test the probability that $p=\alpha$ exactly is zero, and ignoring this possibility would make this explanation slightly less tedious.